# How to import string from another file to blade.php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-blade

i have a screen file let say `screenA.blade.php`. inside this file, i want call a constant file that store some of string let say `constant.js`.

is this possible?

this is what i have inside `screenA.blade.php`

```
<head>
      <script>
              ...
              // some of js code here
              // want call string from constant.js here
              // console.log(string from constant.js)
              ...
      <script>
<head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, put the file constant.js inside  in file screenA.blade.php

```js
//constant.js

//will printed on console
console.log("blablabla")

//will printed on blade file
document.write("blablabla")
```

```html
<!-- screenA.blade.php -->
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="constant.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've inserted the script tag for `constant.js`, then you're able to use the variable defined in the `constant.js` file.

An example for `screenA.blade.php` might look like the below code snippet:

```
<head>
  // path to constant.js file
  <script type="text/javascript" src="constant.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
    // Put javascript code here.

    // Try calling the string defined in constant.js here

    // Using console.log( string from constant.js )

  </script>

</head>
```